# How to extract string between IDs in shell

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I have a string that looks like this:

```
RG="@RG\tID:HS2000-1015_160.7\tDS:ADNI_1380^LP6005117-DNA_G04^ADNI_WGS\tLB:LP6005117-DNA_G04\tPL:illumina\tPU:HS2000-1015_160.7\tSM:ADNI_1380"
```

I want to extract everything after `ID:` and before first the `\t`

and get `HS2000-1015_160.7` as a result. I would like a one-liner if possible.

code I tried:

```
echo ${RG} | grep -oP "(?<=ID:)[^"\t"]*"
```

which gives me `HS2000-1015_160.7\`

Comment: Why `grep`... `grep` is to filter __lines__, not to extract parts of text.

Comment: `grep -oP "(?<=ID:).*?(?=\\\t)"` should work

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
sed 's/.*ID://;s/\\t.*//'
```

- `s/.*ID://` remove everything in front and including `ID:`
- `s/\\t.*//'` remove everything after and including `\t` characters.